# A cosy café in central Paris that is open late at night?

Tags: paris, recommendations, local-knowledge, cafes, romance

I'm looking for a late night café in Paris which has the following requirements:

1. Open late or all night (until at least 1 AM) on Fridays or Saturdays
2. Café or a wine bar
3. No crowd, as few people as possible so preferably a small place
4. It has to be very cosy so no annoying loud music
5. Kinda romantic
6. Price is irrelevant
7. Hopefully not a part of a chain so something privately owned
8. In arrondissements 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 16
9. Maybe an option to ask for a specific song to be played
10. Possibly some pastry or cake available
11. Nice view or a terrace preferred but not a deal breaker

I know this is a tall order but since Paris is quite a popular tourist location famous for romance, I guess some could give me a recommendation.

Comment: I figured I have nothing to lose. Question edited to add the 5th.

Comment: If price is irrelevant, renting one floor of the Tour Eiffel might be an option ;-)

Comment: That certainly wouldn't be cosy and personal.

Comment: Have you tried Yelp?

Comment: Yeah, not very useful. Maybe one place I liked but it also doesn't meet the criteria. I would accept book cafés or any place suitable for let's say a coffee date.

Answer (score 11):

Arguably... there is no single place that can meet all of your requirements and you will be making trade-offs among the various candidates. Acting on the assumption that the primary requirement is that the establishment stays open until 1 or 2 AM, and secondarily that the ambiance is amenable to a romantic encounter, there are several interesting candidates...

### Cosmopolitan

[Le Fumoir](http://www.lefumoir.com/#photos/5) is located at 6 Rue de l'Amiral de Coligny, a stone's throw from the Louvre. There's a "back room" for more a intimate ambiance.  It's open until 2 AM.

### Comfortably Geek

[Dernier Bar avant la Fin du Monde](http://www.dernierbar.com/) is located near Châtelet and offers plush armchairs situated around coffee tables. It has a library-style décor in one part and exhibitions by aspiring artists in another; it's open until 1 AM seven days a week.

### Belle Époque

[Le Zimmer](http://www.lezimmer.com/) located at 1, place du Chatêlet is open until 2 AM except Sunday when it's open until 1 AM.  You can sit outside and watch the world go by or take a seat inside and enjoy the elegance.

### Eternal Paris

In this option you act as the avant garde beforehand and scout out a locale. To do this, follow the Rue Moufftard north to [Place de la Contrescarpe](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Place+de+la+Contrescarpe,+75005+Paris,+France/@48.8444907,2.3495851,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47e671ef33f70389:0x6e61f0d9de92c94a).  In this neighbourhood you will see literally dozens of cafes meeting most of your requirements.  As budget is no object, you may be able to slip the proprietor several hundred Euro thereby convincing him/her to remain open until you leave.  Also if you are seated outside, you will be able to hire a street  musician to play your favourite songs.

[image]

Source: Google Street View, fair use

Note: to check things out, I used the search term:  "*gemütlich cafe paris*".  It turns up lots of results, but the overwhelming majority close at 7 or 8 PM.

Note: about requesting your favourite song, some of the more up-to-date cafes are installing the new Yamaha sound system that lets you request a song from your mobile. I haven't tried this yet but the specs sound fascinating.

Comment: I love Dernier Bar although it does seem quite lively there. Le Zimmer bar in front is nice as well. I'll look into Place de la Contrescarpe bars but most seem quite large. Also, I'm keeping this one without an accepted answer for now as to entice more of them. I appreciate the research that went into this one.

Comment: @rlesko, no need to accept.  I haven't had a chance to get there yet, but I'm informed that the bistro at the new Meliá Hotel is the last word in opulence.  A bit beyond your inner circle of arrondissements though...